# paginacion javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

estoy buscando hacer una paginación con JavaScript. encontre este

```js
$.fn.pageMe = function(opts){
        var $this = this,
            defaults = {
                perPage: 7,
                showPrevNext: false,
                hidePageNumbers: false
            },
            settings = $.extend(defaults, opts);
        
        var listElement = $this.find('tbody');
        var perPage = settings.perPage; 
        var children = listElement.children();
        var pager = $('.pager');
        
        if (typeof settings.childSelector!="undefined") {
            children = listElement.find(settings.childSelector);
        }
        
        if (typeof settings.pagerSelector!="undefined") {
            pager = $(settings.pagerSelector);
        }
        
        var numItems = children.size();
        var numPages = Math.ceil(numItems/perPage);
    
        pager.data("curr",0);
        
        if (settings.showPrevNext){
            $('<li><a href="#" class="prev_link">«</a></li>').appendTo(pager);
        }
        
        var curr = 0;
        while(numPages > curr && (settings.hidePageNumbers==false)){
            $('<li><a href="#" class="page_link">'+(curr+1)+'</a></li>').appendTo(pager);
            curr++;
        }
        
        if (settings.showPrevNext){
            $('<li><a href="#" class="next_link">»</a></li>').appendTo(pager);
        }
        
        pager.find('.page_link:first').addClass('active');
        pager.find('.prev_link').hide();
        if (numPages<=1) {
            pager.find('.next_link').hide();
        }
       pager.children().eq(1).addClass("active");
        
        children.hide();
        children.slice(0, perPage).show();
        
        pager.find('li .page_link').click(function(){
            var clickedPage = $(this).html().valueOf()-1;
            goTo(clickedPage,perPage);
            return false;
        });
        pager.find('li .prev_link').click(function(){
            previous();
            return false;
        });
        pager.find('li .next_link').click(function(){
            next();
            return false;
        });
        
        function previous(){
            var goToPage = parseInt(pager.data("curr")) - 1;
            goTo(goToPage);
        }
         
        function next(){
            goToPage = parseInt(pager.data("curr")) + 1;
            goTo(goToPage);
        }
        
        function goTo(page){
            var startAt = page * perPage,
                endOn = startAt + perPage;
            
            children.css('display','none').slice(startAt, endOn).show();
            
            if (page>=1) {
                pager.find('.prev_link').show();
            }
            else {
                pager.find('.prev_link').hide();
            }
            
            if (page<(numPages-1)) {
                pager.find('.next_link').show();
            }
            else {
                pager.find('.next_link').hide();
            }
            
            pager.data("curr",page);
           pager.children().removeClass("active");
            pager.children().eq(page+1).addClass("active");
        
        }
    };
    
    $(document).ready(function(){
        
      $('#myTable').pageMe({pagerSelector:'#myPager',showPrevNext:true,hidePageNumbers:false,perPage:4});
        
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <table id="myTable" class="table table-hover">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>#</th>
          <th>Table heading</th>
          <th>Table heading</th>
          <th>Table heading</th>
          <th>Table heading</th>
          <th>Table heading</th>
          <th>Table heading</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="success">
          <td>5</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>6</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>7</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
          <td>8</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>9</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>10</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>  
    
    <ul class="pagination pagination-lg pager" id="myPager"></ul>
```

Mi pregunta es: en el **código JavaScript (Jquery)** cuando empieza, de donde sale el `$.fn.pageMe`

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que manejes todo el script del paginador en un js aparte para que lo puedas usar solo cuando lo necesites.

Y la ejecución del paginador está al final.

```
$('#myTable').pageMe({pagerSelector:'#myPager',showPrevNext:true,hidePageNumbers:false,perPage:4});
```

> Donde:
>   **pagerSelector** es tu tabla a paginar. 
>   **showPrevNext** es un bool para mostrar el paginador.
>   **hidePageNumbers** es un bool para mirar el total de registros y páginas.
>   **perPage** es el número de registros que mostrará por página.

Answer (score 0):

Toda la librería de jQuery, al cargarse, se guarda en la variable global `$`, que es una función. Por eso puedes hacer cosas como

```
$('#id').addClass('clase');
```

Pero jQuery permite ser extendido mediante plug-ins o extensiones: puedes programar funcionalidades extras que se añadan a la base de jQuery.

Esto se hace aprovechando que en Javascript las funciones son objetos de primer orden: una función siempre es una instancia de la clase [`Function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Function) y puede tener atributos como cualquier objeto.

El código que expones se *instala* como un plugin de jQuery del modo estándar: añadiendo una función a `$.fn`, que el atributo de jQuery disponible para ello. De hecho es un alias al prototype del objeto $

Answer (score 0):

`$.fn.pageMe` es el nombre de la "nueva funcion" que estas agregando a jquery, en este caso `$` es `jQuery` y le definis una nueva funcion/plugin (`$.fn`) llamada `pageMe` (`$.fn.pageMe`), lo cual te permite luego hacer :

```
$('#myTable').pageMe(opciones)
```

de esa manera `pageMe` "sabe" que `var $this = this` se refiere a `$('#myTable')` y no hace falta pasarle la tabla como parámetro adicional.